# HQL Query Having group of column in IN clause

Tags: hibernate

I need to convert the below SQL query into HQL query.

> select * from table where (column1, column2 , column3) in
>   (('A','B','C'),('D','E','F'));

Comment: OK. In which case you'd best have a read of http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html and then report back if you get stuck.

Comment: @Alex The link gives information about the row value constructor syntax using subqueries. Below mentioned code also works for ID but if I have to set the IN clause for non key column or partail key columns it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below mentioned code works perfectly fine if IN clause contains ID but if I have to set the IN clause for non key column or partail key columns it won't work.

```
List ids = new ArrayList<SomeEntityId>(2);
ids.add( new SomeEntityId(1,12) );
ids.add( new SomeEntityId(10,23) );
ids.add( new SomeEntityId(10,22) );
Query query=s.createQuery( "from SomeEntity e where e.id in (:idList)" );
query.setParameterList( "idList", ids );
List list=query.list();
```

But if I create HQL as "from SomeEntity e where (column1, column2)in (:idList)", it doesn't work.